# The given DateTime key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, containskey

I am a very beginner of C# and programming. I am trying to calculate a few `DateTime` variables. The first one is called `dDate` and second `dDate1` (the previous day of `dDate`), third `dDate2` (the second previous day of `dDate`, i.e., the previous day of `dDate1`), the fourth `dDate3` (the third previous day of `dDate`, i.e., the second previous day of `dDate1` and the previous day of `dDate2`). They must be not holidays or weekends!

I've had all holidays and weekends stored in a dictionary called `nd<DateTime, string>`. The key `DateTime` has a series of date from `2011-01-01` to `2013-01-01`, step by one day and the value `string` is either `TR` or `NT`, a string variable but not boolean. If it is weekend or holiday, string is `NT`, otherwise `TR`.

What I am trying to do is when `dDate` is weekend or holiday, minus one day. For example, `dDate` is `2012-01-02` which is a holiday, change `dDate` to `2012-01-01`, and because it is weekend (Sunday), change it to `2011-12-31`, and it is weekend again, change `dDate` to `2011-12-30`. Same to `dDate1`, `dDate2` and `dDate3`.

The problem here is my code works fine for `dDate`. But it gives an error:

> the given key was not present in the dictionary

when I am doing the same thing for `dDate1`, `dDate2` or `dDate3`. The code is attached below:

```
 private Dictionary<DateTime, string> noDates;
 ...
 noDates = new Dictionary<DateTime, string>();

 public void ImportNoDate()
 {
      string str;
      string[] line = new string[0];
      while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
      {
         line = str.Split(',');
         String date = line[1];
         String flag = line[2];//flag is "NT" or "TR"
         String[] tmp = date.Split('-');
         date = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[0]) + "-" + Convert.ToInt32(tmp[1]) + "-" + Convert.ToInt32(tmp[2]);

         DateTime noDate = DateTime.Parse(date);
         noDates.Add(noDate, flag);
     }
  }

public void ImportdDate()
{
    ...
    DDates dd = new DDates(dDate, noDates); //dDate is defined similar to noDate, it is just another //series of date
}

    //DDates is an auxiliary cs file called DDates.cs
    public DDates(DateTime dd, Dictionary<DateTime, string> nd)
    {
         dDate1 = dDate.AddDays(-1);
         dDate1 = dDate.AddDays(-2);
         dDate3 = dDate.AddDays(-3);

       // dDate is imported from data file and has been Parse
      // to DateTime and it is something like
      // 2012-01-01 12:00:00 AM

     if (nd.ContainsKey(dDate))
     {
        while (nd[dDate].Contains("NT"))
       {
          dDate = dDate.AddDays(-1);
       }
    }

   //It works fine till here:
   if (nd.ContainsKey(dDate1))
   {
      //It gives "the given key was not present in the dictionary" here:
      while (nd[dDate1].Contains("NT"))
      {
        dDate1 = dDate1.AddDays(-1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: You should show how you are populating your dictionary.

Comment: is that all of your code, or are there parts missing inbetween

Comment: You appear to use `dDate` in both the check and the loop for the first part, but in the 2nd part you use `dDate1` in the `if` and `while` checks but you use `dDate2` in the math. Was this intended?

Comment: I am not sure if your entire logic is valid but this is different issue. If you using date as key to dictionary, normally is not a good idea. Obviously, you trying to find this key but "datetime" is such slick data type that you will run into issues. Use strings as keys to dictionaries.

Comment: I don't think a dictionary is the best tool for this. You may be much better of just storing the holiday dates in a hashset or somthing and if it is not contained in the set then it is a non holiday date.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, this program has multiple cs files. But I think it is not multiple-threads.

Comment: @Ek0nomik I have edited the code to show how I am populating the dictionary. It is in another cs file but not the same one as calculating the dDate, dDate1, dDate2, or dDate3

Comment: @SamIam I added more lines. Thank you

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thank you for pointing that out. The 2nd part should all be dDate1 both in if&while and in the math. I've made changes in the code.

Comment: @T.S.The reason I use DateTime is that I wanted to modify it so that they are not holidays or weekend. I've learned it is a bad idea to use 'DateTime' as key though. However, using string in the dictionary I may not be able to make changes on dDate, dDate1. Could you help on this?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks a lot. I am working on it. Will let you know how it goes. I might be slow testing though :)

Comment: Hi All, thanks for all your reply and suggestion. I have solved this problem. It is essentially very easy. What I did was to store all holiday dates in a List variable and set a while loop. While dDate is in the List, dDate = dDate.AddDays(-1). Thank you all again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it looks like what you are trying to do is for a given date find the first non holiday date.

Using a dictionary and storing every possible date is not the correct solution for this.

Personally I think a `HashSet<DateTime>` plus a little math would be the best solution. In fact I was bored so I wrote it up

```
static class HolidayTester
{
    private static HashSet<DateTime> fixedHolidays = new HashSet<DateTime>(new DayOnlyComparer())
        {
            new DateTime(1900,1,1), //New Years
            new DateTime(1900,7,4), //4th of july
            new DateTime(1900,12, 25) //Christmas
        };


    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the most recent workday from a given date.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date">The date to test.</param>
    /// <returns>The most recent workday.</returns>
    public static DateTime GetLastWorkday(DateTime date)
    {
        //Test for a non working day
        if (IsDayOff(date))
        {
            //We hit a non working day, recursively call this function again on yesterday.
            return GetLastWorkday(date.AddDays(-1));
        }

        //Not a holiday or a weekend, return the current date.
        return date;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns if the date is work day or not.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="testDate">Date to test</param>
    /// <returns>True if the date is a holiday or weekend</returns>
    public static bool IsDayOff(DateTime testDate)
    {
      return date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
             date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || //Test for weekend
             IsMovingHolidy(testDate) || //Test for a moving holiday
             fixedHolidays.Contains(testDate); //Test for a fixed holiday
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Tests for each of the "dynamic" holidays that do not fall on the same date every year.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool IsMovingHolidy(DateTime testDate)
    {
        //Memoral day is the last Monday in May
        if (testDate.Month == 5 && //The month is May 
                testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && //It is a Monday
                testDate.Day > (31 - 7)) //It lands within the last week of the month.
            return true;

        //Labor day is the first Monday in September
        if (testDate.Month == 9 && //The month is september
                testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday &&
                testDate.Day <= 7) //It lands within the first week of the month
            return true;


        //Thanksgiving is the 4th Thursday in November
        if (testDate.Month == 11 && //The month of November
            testDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday &&
            testDate.Day > (7*3) && testDate.Day <= (7*4)) //Only durning the 4th week
            return true;

        return false;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// This comparer only tests the day and month of a date time for equality
    /// </summary>
    private class DayOnlyComparer : IEqualityComparer<DateTime>
    {
        public bool Equals(DateTime x, DateTime y)
        {
            return x.Day == y.Day && x.Month == y.Month;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(DateTime obj)
        {
            return obj.Month + (obj.Day * 12);
        }
    }
}
```

Now it does not follow your rules exactly, this code tests if a day is a work day and keeps walking backwards till it hits the first non work day. It would be easy enough to modify, however I did not want to solve your problem exactly so you could learn a little (Unless I misunderstood the algorithm and I did solve the problem, in that case... your welcome)

The way you would use it is simply put in a date and then use that to decide if you are going to return `TR` or `NT`

```
public static string GetDateLabel(DateTime testDate)
{
    if(HolidayTester.IsDayOff(testDate))
        return "NT";
    else
        return "TR";
}
```

If you want to know the last working day you can call that directly from `HolidayTester.GetLastWorkday(DateTime)`

Comment: This is really fancy code! Thank you very much! I am testing it and modifying it to my own needs. Will let you know :)

Comment: Hi Scott, I have solved this problem. It is essentially very easy. What I did was to store all holiday dates in a List variable and set a while loop. While dDate is in the List, dDate = dDate.AddDays(-1). Thank you again! I will next try to integrate your code to my program to make the process more automatic and intelligent!

Comment: @BeginnedCSharp You may want to use a `HashSet` instead of a `List`, the lookups will be much faster.